# How to fix issues with the flash on Nikon D3100?

Tags: nikon, flash, nikon-d3100

When I am in M, A, S, or P modes, my flash goes off without needing to. The built in flash is down, also the button won't pop the flash up. The firmware is updated. Does anyone think this is a mechanical defect with the camera or is there a setting that will keep the flash off no matter what? I have no need for the flash and with this issue I can't take proper pictures since it slows down my sync speed. That is what I was told is going on, I am an amateur. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you clarify your setup? If I correctly understand, you have an external flash, right?

Comment: From your description it seems that even though the flash is recessed it fires. Is this correct? Does the flash pop up when you press the flash button (on the left) when you are in one of the P,A,S,M modes? If not, you have a mechanical problem.

Comment: I experienced the following: D3100 built in flash doesn't open, but it does make the flash, when I wouldn't like it. It only happens with my camera when it's rainy, or when humidity is high. I can't open the flash until the camera gets dried.

Comment: What flash are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If the pop-up flash is going off while it is down, it sounds like the flash believe it is up already but is not popping up.  The spring that pops the flash up may be disconnected or damaged or the sensor that detects when the flash is closed may be malfunctioning.  It might even be both.  I would try manually raising the flash while pushing the flash release (not too hard though).  I'd also try pushing the flash down to see if it registers as being closed when it is pushed down.

In either case, your best bet is probably to contact your camera manufacturer and send it in to be serviced if it is within the warranty period.  If not, unless you are comfortable working on the insides of the camera, it's still probably best to send it out to be repaired.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear. You mention the popup flash is down, therefore I assume you must be speaking of a hot shoe flash?

And then this action seems very normal.  If there is a hot shoe flash that is turned on and is "Ready", then it will always fire in M,A,S, or P mode. For example, people do use their flash for fill in bright sunlight.

If you don't want it to fire, then just remove the flash, or at least turn it off.  If a flash is present and "Ready", M,A,S,P does assume you do want it to fire.  Same with the internal flash, if you open its door, then it will always fire in M,A,S, or P mode.

If it did not fire after you made it Ready, then that would be a problem.

Answer (score -2):

CSI - Photography......

**Evidence:**

-> flash pop up when using in manual modes (M,A,S,P)

-> Firmware updated camera

**Victim affected:**

Name - Scott Peacock . highly affected by the not so flexible shutter speed setting.

**Victim's plea:**

Scott now hates unnatural light that he does not want the flash on his camera to work at all. "let it burn in hell. I just wants to take pictures normally. why cant i do it? Don i have the rights ? after all am just another photographer . Help me somebody !!" comments Scott.

**Case evidence and suspects:**

Possibility 1) The Shooting modes (M,A,S,P) Dial may be broken. even though the Dial is moved, the mode is stuck to Auto mode... (The machines have started taking over the world??? ..... uhh no dude, just get it fixed at an authorized service center)

Possibility 2) There is no more possibility that struck the great CSI for now.

Happy clicking mate :)